# Fast Reports - hide or show a memo on the report using a checkbox

Tags: delphi, fastreport, delphi-10.3-rio

I have placed a checkbox component on my report with the following event handler :

```
procedure CheckBox1OnContentChanged(Sender: TfrxComponent; ModifyObjects: TList; var Refresh: Boolean);
begin
   Memo9.Visible := not CheckBox1.Checked;  
end;
```

When I run the application and test the checkbox functionality on the shown report it does nothing.
Memo is still visible. What am I doing wrong ? Fast Reports is 6 with Delphi Rio.

Comment: If you use the field of the checkbox instead of the checkbox itself it should work fine. You can also try setting the report as double-pass on the general options (this way you ensure that the checkbox already has a value when the event is raised).

Answer (score 0):

The Report is generated after Print() or ShowReport(). Before that you have to create the OnBeforeprint Event where you determine which parts of the report are visible and which are not, using Sender to match the name, example:

```
if Sender.Name='Memo9' then Sender.Visible:=not CheckBox1.Checked;
```